# How to insert Current Date Automatically while inserting data into SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Simply I have an Excel file and I loaded it into SQL Server 2008.

I want to insert current date into the same cells added from Excel while date transferring... then date inserted automatically every time I added data and never lose old date. How can I do this?

```
string ssqltable = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
string myexceldataquery = "select * from [" + ssqltable + "$]";

try
{
    OleDbConnection oconn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + imagepath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");

    string ssqlconnectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Bioxcell;Integrated Security=true";

    OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oconn);
    oconn.Open();

    SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ssqlconnectionstring);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(oledbcmd.ExecuteReader());
    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(i, i);
    }

    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dt);
    oconn.Close();
}
```

I used this but I know insert for only last record
I want to insert current date in newly created rows and doesn't lose previous columns date .. for example when i insert data each time insert new date saving old data with old date

```
SqlCommand Update6 = new SqlCommand("insert into Overseas (Date) Values('" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "')", conn);
Update6.ExecuteScalar();
```

while using

```
 SqlCommand Update6 = new SqlCommand("insert into Overseas (Date) Values (GETDATE())", conn);
                        Update6.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

the result was

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynesI.jpg)
So what's the solution ?

Comment: Hint:  `DEFAULT getdate()` in the column definition.

Comment: sorry don't understand .. can u explain ?

Comment: post Edited....../

Comment: You could set default constraint for that Date column too. If you set means don't want to add Date column when insert.

Comment: i know but i don't know what is the decent sql command for this

Comment: Why ExecuteScalar() on the UPDATE command, there would be no value returned. ExecuteNonQuery() will bring back rows affected (should be 1)

Comment: If you really want to send Date value from code behind then you go with sql parameter way else you can set default constraint for that column and do your stuff. Default constraint will be decent approach.

Comment: Insert not update .. i want to insert current date each time i insert data .. ExecuteNonQuery doesn't work with insert

Comment: can u provide me with example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `GETDATE()` as the default constraint for your Date column of Overseas table.

SQL Command to add constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Overseas
ALTER COLUMN Date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

Post this, you need not pass any value to this column while inserting. Just insert the remaining columns, this will get inserted automatically.

OR

Try this:

```
SqlCommand Update6 = new SqlCommand("insert into Overseas (Date) Values (GETDATE())", conn);
Update6.ExecuteScalar();
```

Based on your DB screenshot hope this query helps:

```
INSERT INTO Overseas (EnglishName,ProductCode,ProductName,TerritoryCode,TerritoryName,Salesvalue,CreditValue,NetSalesValue,Sales,Bonus,Bioxellbricks,BioxellTerritories,Date,ID)
SELECT EnglishName,ProductCode,ProductName,TerritoryCode,TerritoryName,Salesvalue,CreditValue,NetSalesValue,Sales,Bonus,Bioxellbricks,BioxellTerritories,GETDATE(),ID from [exceltablename]
```

Here `Overseas` is your DB table and `exceltablename` is your source table of excel.

Comment: still doesn't work .. I want to insert current date in newly created rows and doesn't lose previous columns date .. for example when i insert data each time insert new date saving old data with old date

Comment: Well, it's working for me             using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Overseas (Id, Date) Values (2, GETDATE())", conn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }   https://ibb.co/gGNby5

Comment: @AmrKamal Can you elaborate the issue you are facing while using the above code?

Comment: i posted screenshot from database

Comment: getdate worked but if i want to add another sperated value this way doesn't work .. i mean in general if i want to add any value in each time i imported the excel file i can't do this .. any help for that ?

Comment: @AmrKamal what is the format of date in your excel file's date column? So accordingly you can convert the same.

Comment: yyyy-mm-dd
i want 
dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: @AmrKamal Database stores date in yyyy-mm-dd format. While fetching it you can convert according to the format you need. Please follow this link.https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use **Datetime.Now();**  function to get current date.

Also Use the zzz format specifier to get the timezone offset as hours and minutes. You also want to use the HH format specifier to get the hours in 24 hour format.

DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")

Result:

```
2011-08-09T23:49:58+02:00
```

Some culture settings uses periods instead of colons for time, so you might want to use literal colons instead of time separators:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH':'mm':'sszzz")
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Hope this will works for you .. Thank you

Comment: i know but i don't know what is the decent sql command for this .. i mean to added current date every time not update it in the whole table

Answer (score 0):

There is a function GETDATE() for this purpose.

> Returns the current database system timestamp as a datetime value
>   without the database time zone offset. This value is derived from the
>   operating system of the computer on which the instance of SQL Server
>   is running.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql

Comment: i know but i don't know what is the decent sql command for this .. i mean to added current date every time not update it in the whole table

Comment: Do I understand right - you want to update all rows that are missing date in Date column? Or you want to insert it in newly created rows?

Comment: in newly created rows and doesn't lose previous columns date .. for example when i insert data each time insert new date saving old data with old date

Comment: CAST( GETDATE() AS Date )  for no time